# OpenSearch Query Intermittent slow response

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, opensearch

Versions (relevant - OpenSearch/Dashboard/Server OS/Browser):

OpenSearch 1.1

Describe the issue:

Intermittent slowness on the query response.

Configuration:

Cluster :
data nodes
Instance type c5.large.search (3)
Dedicated Master Node : r4.large.search (3)
Storage Type : EBS
EBS Volume Type : General Purpose (SSD) - gp2
EBS Size : 10 GiB

Relevant Logs or Screenshots:

Collection size is 1MB ; with below settings:

{
“
spec_proc_comb_exp”: {
“
settings”: {
“
index”: {
“
refresh_interval”: “86400 s”,
“number_of_shards”: “5”,
“plugins”: {
“
index_state_management”: {
“
rollover_skip”: “true”
}
},
“provided_name”: “spec_proc_comb_exp”,
“creation_date”: “1671629334835”,
“number_of_replicas”: “2”,
“uuid”: “aht7O4QQTV6WtozcVCfi1A”,
“version”: {
“
created”: “135227827”
}
}
}
}
}

Query run:
GET spec_proc_comb_exp / _search {
“
query”: {
“
bool”: {
“
must”: [{
“
multi_match”: {
“
query”: “dent”,
“fields”: [“name”, “alias_terms”],
“fuzziness”: “4”
}
}],
“filter”: {
“
match_phrase”: {
“
category”: “Specialty”
}
}
}
}
}

Problem:
We are using OpenSearch as backend to perform exact/fuzzy match for a UI search bar. The index currently used is pretty small 1MB. We see an issue with not stable Response time. Most of the time it is around 100ms; but at times intermittently (10% ) is around 1000 ms or higher.

Request experts to please help troubleshoot this issue. I am new to OpenSearch or any search tech.

Tried reviewing the cluster configuration. Need guidance on the troubleshooting steps in detail. Would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some notes to increase the performance.

1. set `number_of_shards` to 1

It's recommended to keep the shard size between 10-50GB. To do that you can reindex the data into a new index with 1 primary shard.

2. use `term` query rather than `match_phrase`

If you don't need the full-text search feature you can use the `term` query. The term query is faster than match_phrase.

3. decrease `fuzziness` or remove it if you can

The fuzzy query is an expensive query. If you can decrease the query will return faster.

You can [enable the slow logs](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/logs/#slow-logs) to detect slow search logs.

Note: your hardware looks good.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Musab. Will try this and keep you posted about the outcome. Thank you.

Comment: Created a new index with 1 shard and updated my query to basic :

GET proc_ld/_search
{
"query": {
 "bool": {
 "must": [
 {"multi_match": {
 "query": "Acupuncture",
 "fields": ["name"]
 }}
 ]
 }}
 }
 }
}

However I see the same "intermittent" slowness. Looking for your direction Musab.

Comment: To make sure slowness is because of opensearch I recommend you to enable slow logs

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/logs/#slow-logs